# Retuning a JsonResult

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return text to a message box when an error occurs and the return type is JsonResult.

I believe I'm returning a valid type, but when the messagebox appears, it says "undefined".

I have the Json set up as the following:

```
string maxChars = "Upload file size exceeded!";
return Json(new { MaxCharacters = maxChars });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you doing on the client?

Comment: And have you looked at what response is coming back from the call?

Comment: I simply want to return the maxChars message I have above in my question.

Comment: Post the entire method. Post client side code.

Comment: And please make an effort to answer clarifying questions from users. You still haven't shown what's coming over the wire, or anything of your client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are returning this json data from an HttpGet action method, you should explicitly tell the Json method to allow sending back the json data for a GET request.

```
public ActionResult YourMethod()
{
    string maxChars = "Upload file size exceeded!";
    return Json(new { MaxCharacters = maxChars }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in your client side code, you should be accessing the `MaxCharacters` property   of the response coming back from the ajax call.

```
$.get("@url.Action("YourMethod","YourControllerName")",function(res){
  alert(res.MaxCharacters);
});
```